# Setting new column values based on primary key lookup in another table

Tags: mysql, syntax, key, inner-join, calculated-columns

I have a table I want to add an extra column to, where the values in the column are defined by primary key lookup on another table.

I can do this easily by creating a **new** table with the original table, and the desired extra column:

```
CREATE TABLE FG_LABELLED
SELECT FG.*, L.PRODUCT_ALIAS
FROM LABEL_LOOKUP AS L INNER JOIN FG
ON FG.P_ID = L.P_ID;
```

But I cannot figure out the right way to do this  by **adding a column to the existing table**,  as per so:

```
ALTER TABLE FG
    ADD COLUMN PRODUCT_ALIAS VARCHAR(27);

UPDATE FG SET PRODUCT_ALIAS =  EXPRESSION;
```

What can I use here for expression that accomplishes the same effect as creating a new table based on an inner join?

I can't figure out how to ensure the inner join is going to be used to stitch the labels on in the right place, in this context.  If indeed this can be done.

When I try

```
UPDATE  FG
    SET P_LABEL= (SELECT LABEL_LOOKUP.PRODUCT_ALIAS 
    FROM LABEL_LOOKUP INNER JOIN FG ON FG.P_ID = LABEL_LOOKUP);
```

I get

> Error code 1093.  You can't specify target table 'FG' for update in
>   FROM clause.

What is the right way to do what I am trying to do?   Or is it not possible to do it?

thanks,

Heather

p.s.  I am new to SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax for the update should look like this:

```
UPDATE FG 
INNER JOIN LABEL_LOOKUP ON FG.P_ID = LABEL_LOOKUP.P_ID
SET FG.P_LABEL=LABEL_LOOKUP.PRODUCT_ALIAS;
```

Comment: Thanks.  Very useful.   I'm puzzled though when parsing this.  Inner join takes two args usually, but here it seems to only have one?

Comment: Forgot the fieldname in the join, damn copy&paste, added fieldname to the join.

Comment: I'd mostly used inner join in the context of 'from', e.g.  from FG inner join GP on (FG.id = GP.id).  And I had been thinking of inner join as having args FG and GP.   I think what's confusing me here is that FG in line 1 seems to serve as argument to UPDATe and as arg to INNER join at the same time.

Comment: You do the select or update on a "table". A table in these two cases ( not for delete ) can be ... as you now ... a table.
A join is kind of a table, so you can think of just a new table if you have a join in select or update statements.
    (fg JOIN gp ON fg.id=gp.id) AS newtable

Comment: AHA.  Parens help.  tx.

Comment: Strange   update (FG inner join  Label on FG.id = Label.id) set .. xxx.   This strange to me as it updating to a join table. I think we can update to one table only not the join table.

Comment: @suhao399 You can update on joins (INNER JOINS), but you have to specify which side of the join you want to update